# increase id value of anchor element in dynamically created rows

Tags: jquery, html

I am currently using the following javascript function code to dynamically duplicate table rows:

```
  <script language="javascript">     
     function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

        var document.getElementById("selectlist").value

        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;

            //alert(newcell.childNodes);
            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                case "text":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                        break;
                case "checkbox":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                        break;
                case "select-one":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                        break;
            }

        }
    }
   </script>
```

I would like to increase dynamically increase the id value of an anchor element so that jquery functions can work despite having duplicate class names. HTML code is:

```
   <table width="300">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>&nbsp; </th>
                        <th width="190"> License Plate</th>
                        <th> Amount </th>
                        <th>&nbsp; </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="dynamic_row_8">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="20"><input type="checkbox" name="add_or_remove_row"/></td>
                        <td width="144"><input type="text" name="garage_for[]" class="field"/></td>
                        <td width="144"><input type="text" name="garage_amount[]"class="field_medium"/ class="disabled_field" disabled></td>
                        <td><a class="modal_trigger" href="#modal"><img src="images/icons/add.png"></a></td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3"><div align="right">
                            <input type="button" value="Add Row" onClick="addRow('dynamic_row_8')" />
                            <input type="button" value="Delete Row" onClick="deleteRow('dynamic_row_8')" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
```

I want to be able to increment the anchor element id by 1 with each duplicated row.

Thanks

Comment: There isn't any jQuery in your code...are you looking for a jQuery or javascript solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery would not have any problems with duplicated class names on the anchor tag.
Let's say for example you would like to listen for click events on your anchor tags and you would want to know which anchor tag was clicked, all you would have to do is:

```
$('#dynamic_row_8').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
  // $(this) is the target element which fired the event handler.
  console.log($(this));
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

But if you still would like to add an individual id to each dynamically create anchor you could do the following.

In your **addRow** function you have a *switch* to check the input type of the input elements in each cell, since an anchor is not an input you could use the *default* case to increase the id of the anchor by adding up to the **rowCount**. At the end of your switch statement do the follwoing:

```
switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
  //...
  default:
    newcell.childNodes[0].setAttribute('id', rowCount += 1);
}
```

In your switch you are checking for "**select-one**",

```
case "select-one":
  newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
  break;
```

this will never be true since "**select-one**" is not an input type.

There is also an error in your function.

```
var document.getElementById("selectlist").value // not a valid assingment!!!
```

Guess you forgot to give your variable a name.